# Highcharts error 13, but rendering Div exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to implement Highcharts with this tutorial https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart but get this error:

*Uncaught (in promise) Error: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13*

It means the div does to render to doesn't exist, but I am pretty sure I have a div with the right class in my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.30.7/react-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="/js/dashboard.js"></script>
    <!--link custom css file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Your Dashboard</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-7">
                <h3 class="text-center">Calories Today</h3>
                <div class="top-left" id="cal-line">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <h3 class="text-center">Calories Over Time</h3>
                <div class="top-right" id="cal-today" style="width:100% height:400px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my JS in /js/dashboard.js:

```
/*global React*/
/*global ReactBootstrap*/
/*global ReactDOM*/
/*global fetch*/
/*global location*/
/*global Highcharts*/
/*global $*/

//variable to hold user data from API fetch
let user = {};

const fb_id = location.pathname.replace("/users/","");

$(document).ready(function() {

fetch("https://www.url.com/usersdata/" + fb_id)
        .then(rsp => rsp.json())
        .then(json => {
        //we fetched the user data    
            if(json.error && json.error.message){
                throw new Error(json.error.message);
            } 

            user = json;
            console.log(json);

            $(function(){
               const myChart = Highcharts.chart('top-right',{

                 chart:{
                     type: 'bar'
                 },
                 title:{
                     text: 'Calories Over Time'
                 },
                 xAxis:{
                     categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
                 },
                 yAxis:{
                     title:{
                         text: 'Fruit eaten'
                     }
                 },
                 series: [{
                     name: 'Jane',
                     data: [1,0,4]
                 },{
                     name: 'John',
                     data: [5,7,3]
                 }]

               });

            });

        });

});
```

Anyone can help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: OK, the documentation states that the first argument to `Highcharts.chart` is **The id or a reference to a DOM element where the chart should be rendered** ... so use the ID not the CLASS of that element. hint: it's **cal-today**

Comment: that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `<div>` tag you should refer your chart using "id" not "class".

Also, when you give reference to your external js which contains the highchart, add it in the body tag not in the head.

This is from my working code.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sytlels.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="highChart.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```